# I edited grub.cfg and linux mint won't boot now (virtual box)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, virtualbox, grub

So I was trying to boot DOS on Linux mint and found an old article, which told me to add this:

```
title DOS update utility
   root  (hd0,0)
   kernel /memdisk
   initrd /dosboot.img.gz
```

in grub.cfg. I did that and every time I try to boot, I get the following error:

[image: the error]

I can't access grub, I'm just stuck here, even If i press 'e' while booting. I've tried the following: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/245 but no luck so far. What can I do?

Comment: Mount "on" Linux mint?  Do you mean you are attempting to set up a dual-boot and Linux Mint is your primary/only current OS? or are you setting up a grub boot loader in a VM on Linux?  When you say that you've tried following those instructions, what is happening?  Do you have a separate grub partition?  If you followed old instructions, they may have been for Grub 1, the instructions you linked to for reinstalling are for Grub2.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the old article you reference?

Comment: @DougHendrick Yeah I was trying to set up a grub boot loader in a VM on linux, so that it would boot DOS too. When I put in the following command: `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda`
I get the following error: `Failed to get canonical path of /cow`

Comment: @DougHendrick this is the old article: http://idolinux.blogspot.si/2009/10/create-dos-boot-disk-for-cd-or-grub.html